# Return img from php on nginx

Tags: php, nginx

The following appears to be pretty standard code to return an image from a database using php.
When I run the code using the php cli (and a hardcoded name), I get the correct contents (unintelligible blob that when saved to file can be displayed statically) from my database. However when I try to access the same via my browser, nothing appears. The dev tools in chrome report that a header size of 183 B and content size 0.

```
<?php
$conn = odbc_connect('MySQL','','');
$query = "SELECT img, length(img) as length from imgs WHERE name = '".$_GET['name']."'";
$result = odbc_exec($conn, $query);

$row = odbc_fetch_array($result);
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: ".$row['length']);
echo $row['img'];
?>
```

I'm thinking maybe this has something to do with my nginx config file

```
server {
    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location /images/ {
        root /data;
    }

    location ~ /.*\.php$ {
        if ($fastcgi_script_name ~ /(.*\.php)$) {
            set $valid_fastcgi_script_name $1;
        }
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    /var/www/cgi-bin/$valid_fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is that the whole script you have there?

Comment: that's it. Essentially I would like `example.com/img.php?imagename.jpg` to open as an image like [Google png](https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you need to flush the fastcgi request after having sent the content to the browser.
You should use `fastcgi_finish_request`, in order to flush the request.
See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php

Comment: This shouldn't affect the output of the script in any way.

Comment: no effect when running in browser. incidentally, when running from php cli i get `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function fastcgi_finish_request()` despite having php-fpm installed.

Comment: Hum... do you have any content if you put an `error_log('Should go there'); exit(__FILE__ . ' ' . __LINE__);` statement at the top of your script?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was once again foiled by SELinux. Thanks to all anyway